# Not All Xaxis Labels Showing On Chart Control From Bound Dataset

Tags: vb.net, dataset, mschart, databound

I have a problem with a couple of various chart controls that I am trying to bind to different datasets. Basically, when I run the following query, my chart control will only show every 2nd Label on the X Axis no matter what size I make the chart.

```
SELECT MID(MONTHNAME(created_at),1,3) as Month, COUNT(created_at) AS TotalCreatedCalls, COUNT(closed_at) AS TotalClosedCalls FROM call_detail WHERE DATE(created_at) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND CURDATE() GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)
```

However, if I remove the MONTHNAME statement and just return the MONTH, all 12 months appear fine on the X Axis Label as numbers.

```
SELECT MONTH(created_at) as Month, COUNT(created_at) AS TotalCreatedCalls, COUNT(closed_at) AS TotalClosedCalls FROM call_detail WHERE DATE(created_at) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND CURDATE() GROUP BY MONTH(created_at)
```

I have the same exact issue with another chart control where I am trying to show peoples names along the X Axis, but I only get every 5th name.  However, I also have another chart control with pulls 7 days and shows the week name on the X Axis and that seems to work fine.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question at the following site [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10712371/showing-all-values-in-chart-control-xaxis)

It had to do with the Minor and Major ticks of the Axis LabelStyles and it just required some playing around and tweaking to give my the results I needed.

Answer (score 5):

Add this code it will help you

chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1